# What does bootstrap mean in scikit-learn's BaggingClassifier?

Tags: machine-learning, python

I just started using scikit-learn and was learning about the BaggingClassifier. I am a little confused on what bootstrap means. The meaning on the scikit-learn website doesn't make sense. Just asking for a little help. Thanks.

Comment: See page 187 of ISLR here --> https://www.statlearning.com/ (click to download first edition).

Comment: Thank You :-)  I think it will help a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bootstrapping methods resample from the data with replacement to "fake more data". You've got many good explanations in [stats SE](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/bootstrap?tab=Votes). For bagging this means sampling from the training data a "new" data set for each base estimator that is fitted.

Comment: Your explanation really helped me understand. Thank You